# Using matlab to calculate and plot a set of elastic data

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm considering using Matlab to plot a graph for some sets of elastic data.

Here is the question:

In the mantle, density varies from 2.0 to 5.0 g/cm^3, the bulk modulus varies from 0.0 to 6.6 x 10^11 N/m^2, and the rigidity modulus varies from 0.0 to 2.9. The propose is to determine the greatest effect on P-wave velocities.

The formula for this is: v = sqrt((K+(4/3)u)/p)
which:
v P-wave velocity
p density
k bulk modulus
u rigidity modulus

So now I wish to represent a graph for all value of v in order to observe the greatest value, but I have no idea how to do that.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What are the units on the rigidity modulus?

Comment: Anyways, this is a strange thing to plot. You have 3 independent variables and 1 dependent variable... you would need to find a way to visualize a 4 dimensional equation. If you're simply looking to get the maximum p-wave velocity, it's basically trivial considering the equation.